# Xfce does not launch some programs

Tags: linux-mint, xfce

for some reason, I'm unable to launch programs from Xfce since yesterday. Clicking on icons in the panel or the applications menu simply shows no effect for stuff like e. g. Firefox, Thunderbird, VLC Player or Totem. Others like Terminal, GIMP or LibreOffice work as usual. The problem also occurs when I try to launch these from the terminal. Additionally, the notification area disappeared from the panel and it is not possible to add it again in the settings (don't know if this is related to the first problem).

Any advice on what to do? I already tried reinstalling Xfce.

Thank you in advance.

*(Xfce 4.12, Linux Mint 18.1, 4.4.0-116)*

Comment: I assume you get no error messages when you start these programs from a terminal? What does `firefox; echo $?` report?

Comment: You are right, no error messages. `firefox; echo $?` reports `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today's updates seem to have fixed it. Thanks anyway for your answers and any hints on which package(s) caused the problem are still appreciated.